# How do I get the raw Android camera buffer in C using JNI?

Tags: java, android, c, camera, java-native-interface

I've been searching Google and StackOverflow exhaustively and cannot find this.  Maybe I'm missing something obvious.  Thanks!

(This is because the Java implementation of the preview callback [even with buffer] is too inefficient.)

Comment: do you have only usual or any extra (maybe root) privileges?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this. Coz I'm looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I made a little investigation on topic. This [presentation](http://wenku.baidu.com/view/ced8a5c9da38376baf1faebb.html) (from p.277, Chinese) helped a lot.

#### Camera preview call chain

As others mentioned, you can get a buffer using a `Camera.setPreviewCallback` method.
Here's how it happens there (a verbose version):

1. User calls `Camera.startPreview()` which is a native function.
2. `android_hardware_Camera_startPreview` calls `startPreview` method of C++ `Camera` class.
3. `Camera` calls a `startPreview` method of `ICamera` interface
4. `ICamera` makes an `IPC` call to remote client.
5. It calls a `setCameraMode` method of `CameraService` class.
6. `CameraService` sets a window to display a preview and calls a `startPreview` method of `CameraHardwareInterface` class.
7. The latter tries to call a `start_preview` method on particular `camera_device_t` device. 
   *I didn't looked up further but it should perform a call to the driver.*
8. When image arrives, `dataCallback` of `CameraService` is invoked.
9. It passes data to `handlePreviewData` method of client.
10. Client either copies the buffer or sends it directly to the `ICameraClient`.
11. `ICameraClient` sends it over `IPC` to the `Camera`.
12. `Camera` calls a registered listener and passes buffer to `JNI`.
13. It invokes a callback in Java class. If user provided a buffer with `Camera.addCallbackBuffer` then it copies to the buffer first.
14. Finally Java class `Camera` handles the message and invokes a `onPreviewFrame` method of `Camera.PreviewCallback`.

As you can see 2 `IPC` calls were invoked and buffer was copied at least twice on steps 10, 11. First instance of raw buffer which is returned by `camera_device_t` is hosted in another process and you cannot access it due to security checks in `CameraService`.

#### Preview surface

However, when you set a preview surface using either `Camera.setPreviewTexture` or `Camera.setPreviewDisplay` it is be passed directly to the camera device and refreshed in realtime without participation of all the chain above. As it's documentation says:

> Handle onto a raw buffer that is being managed by the screen compositor.

Java class `Surface` has a method to retrieve it's contents:

```
public static native Bitmap screenshot(int width, int height, int minLayer, int maxLayer);
```

But this API is hidden. See i.e. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888191/how-do-i-build-the-android-sdk-with-hidden-and-internal-apis-available) for a way to use it.

Comment: Two comments to this excellent summary. **1.** Steps 10-11 _may_ involve `memcpy`, but most likely they only pass the buffer without copy, by using inter-process memory sharing. **2.** The `screenshot` method for **[Surface](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android_view_Surface.cpp)** copies pixels, it also involves IPC, and possibly color conversion, so it would be a mistake to use it for better performance. **2a.** This `screenshot` method produces an RGB bitmap, while most video encoding needs YUV.

Answer (score 5):

There is no public API to do what you want; the only official (that is, guaranteed to work) method is the Java-level preview callbacks set up through calling [Camera.setPreviewCallback()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewCallback%28android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback%29).  In Android > 3.0, you can also use [Camera.setPreviewTexture()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewTexture%28android.graphics.SurfaceTexture%29) to route preview data to the GPU, and process it there using GLES (or read it back to the CPU). The GPU path is what the ICS AOSP camera application uses for its video effects.

Presumably, OpenCV and others have looked through the Android framework native code, and have bypassed the Java Camera API, talking to the services below directly.

This is fairly dangerous, because there is absolutely no guarantee that those interfaces won't change between Android versions, since they are not part of the public API. Using them may be fine now, and then when a user upgrades their device, your app will stop working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [OpenCV for Android](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/OpenCV4Android).  Their [advanced tutorials](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/AndroidSamples) show how to use JNI and there is a NativeProcessor object in their camera package.