# Get more fps from android opencv camera

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

I'm trying to get more fps(frames per second) from android camera.

I'm using Android opencv java camera view and setting the resolution to 118*142 but the camera fps is about 16. It doesn't change when I use an algorithm like Canny or sepia.

I want to know how can I get the highest fps since the original camera itself can reach 30 fps.

## Pay attention

I get the same fps whether I use Canny or not. I Googled a lot before asking.

How can I get more fps from OpenCV Android camera?

Comment: Are you using `setRecordingHint(true)`?

Comment: no I didn't set anything for this method. what does it do?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRecordingHint(boolean) -- I've found that setting it will increase the maximum frame rate on some devices. It may also alter the resolution.

Comment: I didn't see any parameters like this for opencv camera!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Android camera native access : startPreview() vs startRecording()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826363/android-camera-native-access-startpreview-vs-startrecording)

You should access the native camera interface if you need more FPS.  It will not be as portable as OpenCV but will give you the best performance possible.  The slowness comes in when martialing data between Java and C++.