# APIs not getting hidden even after using the annotation @hide in Android

Tags: android, hide, javadoc

I am writing my own SDK on android and as such creating my own jar.
Now I create documentation of my SDK using droiddoc tool.

In my framework files(.java), there are many APIs that I have marked with @hide
Now this is the current state:

a) all APIs marked with @hide are hidden in documentation.

b) These APIs marked hidden is INCLUDED in class files in generated jar file.(I use Java decompiler to check this).

Now when I include this jar in eclipse and use Ctrl+space on my class object to find its options, i can see that hidden APIs are actually visible and accessible here.

Am I missing anything here, and do I need to add any special flags in make file? Or is this a normal behaviour?

Comment: Short answer: this is normal behavior concerning java's class visibility rules. I don't know any annotation that could hide the class access from source code.

Comment: Hi George, thanks for response, but If you check for example :BluetoothDevice.java - A typical f/w file in android, there are several APIs with @hide. Now from default android jar file available in sdk, I cannot access these APIs in eclipse(basically its not visible). Any idea why this difference?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that:

> android.jar has all classes from com.android.internal removed, and all
>   classes, enums, fields and methods marked with @hide removed as well

So the classes with @hide are not included on jar -> that's why they are not accessible in eclipse.
Furthermore:

> When you launch your application on device it loads framework.jar
>   (roughly this is equivalent of android.jar on the device) which is
>   uncut and has all the internal API classes and all hidden API
>   components.

Have a look over [this post](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888191/how-do-i-build-the-android-sdk-with-hidden-and-internal-apis-available)
Hope you find an alternative solution for hiding things

Comment: Hi George, thanks for the reply. I have already been through the links you posted above. Instead of manual removal, I was thinking if there is any possibility of building separate jar via android make file whose build scripts already does the removal for me. Let me know if you find any such thing.