# Why is this Java method available only using reflection?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I'm new to reflection, as a matter of fact, I never had to use it until I ran into the following problem -

I tried to use a method called `getCompatibilityInfo` defined in a class called Resources, but I saw that the only way of doing it is to call it like this:

```
Resources.class.getMethod("getCompatibilityInfo");
```

I can get an instance of Resources using a method called `getResources()`, so why isn't it accessible using `getResources().getCompatibilityInfo()`?

The class source code is **[here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/content/res/Resources.java/?v=source)**

Thanks!

Comment: because instanciating Resources is not sufficient. you have seen the code, you know there are certain parameters to the constructor, and the empty constructor is private, because it serves only for the System resources.

Comment: because of `@hide` annotation

see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888191/how-do-i-build-the-android-sdk-with-hidden-and-internal-apis-available

Comment: @Heuster, it doesn't compile.

Comment: farincz, I'm looking for more info about the @hide annotation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`Resources` has not an empty public constructor. So `new Resources()` will give you a compile time error, also getCompatibilityInfo() is not part of the public API

Comment: You're right, I forgot to write it the right way. I edited my question and now I use getResources to obtain an instance. Still, it doesn't compile...

Answer (score 2):

That's something that only happens in Android, because *android.jar* has all the methods marked with `@hide` removed. This only matters while compiling, because *android.jar* is only used for development.

Long explanation on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9565020/1073063).