# Using internal android classes

Tags: android, internal

I want to use an android internal class, com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils .

I searched for examples and I got this:

```
LockPatternUtils lpu = new LockPatternUtils(this.getContentResolver());
```

However, i cant import, autimport does not appear and manually doing

```
import com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils
```

doesnt work.

How is this handled? I think there was something about creating an interface but not sure about it

EDIT: I got this:

```
  boolean patternLocked = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(
     getContentResolver(),Settings.System.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED, 0)==1;
```

That works for the pattern lock, but i cant know about the pin or password lock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is this handled?

Those classes are only available as part of full firmware builds, not from Android SDK apps.

Comment: The Telephony class is internal too but it is possible to be accessed in 3rd party app. Doesnt this have a solution like that?

Comment: @JesusS: "The Telephony class is internal too but it is possible to be accessed in 3rd party app" -- not reliably. Anything that is internal can and will be modified (or even removed) by device manufacturers and ROM modders.

Answer (score 6):

Use reflection to access the internal Android method getActivePasswordQuality (line 350 of [LockPatternUtils.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/52c489cd63cca0361f374f7cb392018fabfa8bcc/core/java/com/android/internal/widget/LockPatternUtils.java)) and compare the int it returns to the int for any of the [DevicePolicyManager Constants](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html):

```
protected boolean isSecure() {

    String LOCK_PATTERN_UTILS = "com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils";

    try {
        Class<?> lockPatternUtilsClass = Class.forName(LOCK_PATTERN_UTILS);
        Object lockPatternUtils = lockPatternUtilsClass.getConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(this);
        Method method = lockPatternUtilsClass.getMethod("getActivePasswordQuality");
        int lockProtectionLevel = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(method.invoke(lockPatternUtils)));

        // Then check if lockProtectionLevel == DevicePolicyManager.TheConstantForWhicheverLevelOfProtectionYouWantToEnforce, and return true if the check passes, false if it fails
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: `getActivePasswordQuality` was changed in API `23` and now requires an int argument (the user id). Is there a way to determine the user id of the current user without `MANAGE_USERS` permission?

Answer (score 2):

You can not use Android internal classes, they do not come with the public SDK.

You can build your own SDK exposing them more or less as they do here [How do I build the Android SDK with hidden and internal APIs available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888191/how-do-i-build-the-android-sdk-with-hidden-and-internal-apis-available)

This is not recommended because you will have no guarantees.