# How to access the android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager in Kitkat

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am trying to use the hidden camera2 api mentioned here for google glass. http://www.slideshare.net/lbk003/an-devcon2013-camera3kaurfinal

I have confirmed that Camera2 APIs are available on my kitkat glass using github link in the slides.

The dex files has been reverse engineered to get access to camera2 packages using the dex2jar method below.
[How do I build the Android SDK with hidden and internal APIs available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888191/how-do-i-build-the-android-sdk-with-hidden-and-internal-apis-available)

I have written a simple camera api using the slides and using camera2video example (google for camera2video example for Android L). There are  differences in the Android L camera2 api and the hidden camera2 api in Android kitkat.

Howeever, the below lines gives an compilation error - CAMERA_SERVICE cannot be resolved or is not a field.
manager = (CameraManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

Looks like Context.CAMERA_SERVICE is not available. Has anyone successful gained access to camera2 api in Android kitkat?

Comment: This was resolved by reverse engineering the class code to see that the Context.CAMERA_SERVICE = "camera" string.

Answer (score 0):

Just because the incomplete camera2 API source code is included in Android KitKat, it doesn't mean that any specific device actually supports the new API.

It's unlikely that you'll be able to this run on Glass.