# Access protected variable of android class

Tags: android, launcher

Recently I complied the source code of adw-launcher, some of the class of this project use protected variable of android classes.
Below is a code snippet:

```
 @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        if (mLeft != left || mRight != right || mTop != top || mBottom != bottom) {
            mBackgroundSizeChanged = true;
        }
        return super.setFrame(left, top, right, bottom);
    }
```

mLeft, mRight are all protected.

How to go about this ?
I am totally noob in this, need your guidance.

I went through this link: [How do I build the Android SDK with hidden and internal APIs available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888191/how-do-i-build-the-android-sdk-with-hidden-and-internal-apis-available)

If I replace new jar file, hope it will access these new files, will I have to alter these files ? I just don't have any idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use powerful (and dangerous) Reflection API of Java at your own risk!

```
   try {
        Field field = TargetClass.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);

        result = field.get(targetObject);

        field.setAccessible(false);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

to get result as `int` :

```
int result = field.getInt(targetObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `protected` members outside their packages - this is by design of Java.

You might be able to access it using Java reflection, but this isn't advisable.

```
 Field[] f = ClassName.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
```

Then, simply `f[i].setAccessible(true)` to allow yourself to read from them. But this definitely isn't advisable unless truly needed.

Comment: But then how do they compile the source? For ex they have used mleft variable of view which is protected. I have updated quest.

Comment: @viv I'm sorry, I'm just not sure what you're asking here. This is how you access protected variables of other classes with reflection (in, albeit, a rather dangerous way). What is it you need to know?

Comment: The above code snippet is from a class that extends TextView still eclipse, showing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK hidden classes are only available to framework level apps/code. You need to link `framework.jar` and `framework2.jar` with your code to access hidden APIs. But then also your app might raise a `Security Exception` at runtime.

As suggested in link you provided you will have to build source to obtain those jars. Those protected variables must be coming from base class. If i understand your question correctly that base class might be coming from framework jars.

Comment: You understood my question well, even if I have compiled those jars, the variables will still be protected, then ?

Comment: Protected variables can only be accessed by subclasses. You need to inherit from that class which is having those variables.