# Where can I find android.security.KeyStoreException?

Tags: android, sdk

In which SDK, jar this class can be found? I need to check at runtime if an exception is an instance of it.

I know this class can be found in AOSP sources. But this doesn't help much in runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a hidden class in the Android SDK (see [the Android 8.1 edition](http://aosp.opersys.com/xref/android-8.1.0_r18/xref/frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyStoreException.java)).

Comment: Mark, how to compile against hidden class in Android SDK?

Comment: If I workaround to build it like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287570/exposing-hidden-apis-android-l-sdk-21-in-android-studio. Is it guarnteed that app will not crash in production?

Comment: @EugenMartynov: "how to compile against hidden class in Android SDK?" -- you can't. "Is it guarnteed that app will not crash in production?" -- I would not do that. Call `Class.forName()` and look it up at runtime, bearing in mind that this might break on Android P. Or, call `getClass().getName()` on the exception and compare it to `android.security.KeyStoreException` (though this wouldn't handle subclasses).

Comment: Thank you! I will actually compare class names since it is the only one available strategy for now.

Comment: Or just ignore cause and relay on the `ProviderException` in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can download the android sdk source, see this link:

[Android SDK source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832122/android-sdk-source-code?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

With regards to checking the exception type at runtime, you can do the following (in Kotlin - transcribe to Java if required):

```
fun doSomething() {
    try {
        // Do something that may cause an exception
    } catch (ex: KeyStoreException) {

    }
}
```

or:

```
fun checkType() {
    try {
        // Something that could throw an exception
    } catch(ex: Exception) {
        when (ex) {
            is KeyStoreException -> {
                // Handle
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can not compile this code. Did you try? The thingy this class is not visible in Android SDK.

Comment: Compiles fine for me. It is Kotlin however, like I said in my answer you may need to transcribe to Java if you're writing in Java.

Comment: Is it `android.security.KeyStoreException` or `java.security.KeyStoreException`?

Comment: java.security.KeyStoreException, for which android.security.KeyStoreException is simply an alias (as far as I know). From the official docs (note the package name):

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStoreException.html

Comment: No, it is not the alias. Please don't get wrong with it :)

Comment: Tom, sorry that my question looks vague. The problem that this class is not visible in Android SDK and it is completely different class than you pointed out. So the question was not how to write code against of class that I can not find in my compile path

Answer (score 1):

This is a hidden class in Android . This can only be accessed by the framework or below layers and system apps , cannot be used by third party applications . You can check out the defination in the below link .

http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/keystore/java/android/security/KeyStoreException.java.

There are 3 such classes in Android . All the 3 are under different packages and used in different context .

http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/search?q=&defs=&refs=&path=%22KeyStoreException.java%22&hist=&project=art&project=bionic&project=bootable&project=build&project=cts&project=dalvik&project=developers&project=development&project=device&project=docs&project=external&project=frameworks&project=hardware&project=kernel&project=libcore&project=libnativehelper&project=packages&project=pdk&project=platform_testing&project=prebuilts&project=sdk&project=system&project=test&project=toolchain&project=tools

Comment: Thanks, how in runtime check if an exception has exactly this class?

Comment: the only way I can think of is using reflection .