# Build custom SDK with AOSP changes

Tags: android, sdk, android-source

I am trying to build my app (uses many hidden api and properties) in android studio. I have modified the AOSP code to expose these hidden apis. In order to make the build successful I have added the classes.jar as the external lib to my project. But that doesn't resolve the issue. It was still showing errors :

```
error: cannot find symbol method getService()   
error: cannot find symbol variable userSetLocale    
error: cannot find symbol method getInstance()  
error: cannot find symbol variable INJECT_INPUT_EVENT_MODE_WAIT_FOR_FINISH  
error: cannot find symbol variable INJECT_INPUT_EVENT_MODE_ASYNC
```

Now I am trying to make the custom SDK with this modified AOSP code.

Note : Already tried and failed with the following solutions

- [Exposing hidden APIs android L (SDK 21) in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287570/exposing-hidden-apis-android-l-sdk-21-in-android-studio)
- [How do I build the Android SDK with hidden and internal APIs available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888191/how-do-i-build-the-android-sdk-with-hidden-and-internal-apis-available)
- https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api

Can anyone help to build custom SDK based on the modified AOSP code

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in you root project's build.gradle. ${rootDir}/libs/framework.jar is the jar build from you aosp code.

```
subprojects {
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs.add("-Xbootclasspath/p:${rootDir}/libs/framework.jar")
    }
 }
}
```

There are red errors in the editor. But it can be build successful.
Demo project:https://github.com/auxor/AppWithModifiedFramework/

Comment: This solution works for me. And can you check whether the classes.jar is right? Does the classes.jar contains the modified hidden api?

Comment: It works if you add a new class. It doesnt work for hidden methods on classes that are already exposed in normal SDK (android.jar).
For example you cannot add a method or class to Activity or Context with this approach. The only way is to replace the android.jar in SDK folder

Comment: @RickSanchez  I have add new api for already exposed classes in Android 5.0. It works.

Comment: Wierd. It did not for me when I tried this about a month ago. If you have time, can you post a simple android project in github complete with the framework.jar and any other relevant changes to build.gradle that make it work?  It'd be pretty useful if you found a way to make it work without replacing android.jar.

Comment: @RickSanchez https://github.com/auxor/AppWithModifiedFramework/

Comment: I don't have issue with the framework.jar. But during build time, it is still referring to the api from the SDK not from the framework.jar. I have changed the orderEntry of SDK to the last in app.iml. But after gradle sync it is again changed to default.

Comment: Studio is able to resolve custom changes in framework.jar.  But while building i get compile error says cannot resolve method. Any help ?

Comment: @MUHAMMEDRAFEEQKARAKKADAN I have no idea about why it does not work for you. You may have a look at github.com/auxor/AppWithModifiedFramework.

Comment: @Yong Are you sure your project builds successful after hidden api or property is used? I have added these lines in your project : Configuration config = am.getConfiguration();  config.userSetLocale = true; after this the build failed with error : cannot find symbol variable userSetLocale

Comment: @MUHAMMEDRAFEEQKARAKKADAN Do you have any error, when you don't modify anything? ActivityManager.addMode and ActivityManager2 are new added API.  And ActivityManager don't have method getConfiguration

Comment: @MUHAMMEDRAFEEQKARAKKADAN In the editor, it may show red error. But it can be build successful. Try "./gradlew assemble" in the terminal or Run it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing the orderEntry of sdk in app.iml and giving the absolute path of framework.jar in modules build.gradle