# How to develop android app using internal API or hidden API?

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm trying to develop an app using TVInputFramework. In android SDK all API s are not available. I want use HdmiControlService (a system service) in my app. The only way is using internal API or hidden API in my app.

1. How to develop apps using these API s.
2. Is there any Tutorials.
3. Can i use my android studio to develop this kind of app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a mini-guide on how to use TIF in [Developing a TV Input Service](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/tif/tvinput.html#TIFCompanion).

> Create a TV Input Service Using the TIF Companion Library
>
> The TIF Companion Library is a framework that provides extensible
>   implementations of common TV input service features. Use the TIF
>   Companion Library to quickly and easily create your own TV input
>   service that follows best practices for Android TV.

There is even a sample app in Github called [Sample Android TV Channel App (TV Input) using TIF](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-sample-inputs).

Comment: Hi noogui. Thanks for your reply.. Actually i want to use HdmiControlService in my app. https://source.android.com/devices/tv/HDMI-CEC.html. which is part of TVInputFramework. Can you help me on that

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your own Android Sdk and produce an android.jar file.

You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888191/how-do-i-build-the-android-sdk-with-hidden-and-internal-apis-available)