# How to Use Hidden API classes

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to use Hidden API classes for **API level 28 or 29** in Android Studio.I don't want to use reflection to access these classes .I have gone through multiple links i.e [How do I build the Android SDK with hidden and internal APIs available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888191/how-do-i-build-the-android-sdk-with-hidden-and-internal-apis-available/13401572#comment112063930_13401572) as all they are mentioning copy jar file from this path  **out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/classes.jar** but i am not able to find this path to get this jar files to access hidden API classes.I know i am missing some steps to get this path.Please help to find this path so i can use this jar to access hidden APIs.

Comment: There isnt really a way to use them, You can try using a modified `android.jar` file that includes all the framework classes. https://medium.com/@hardiannicko/create-your-own-android-hidden-apis-fa3cca02d345 I had limited success with that before

Comment: @tyczj i have tried this way..in this way i have to modify the my custom own jar and then replace to android-sdk- platform -api level  but i dont want to use replace my own sdk android jar

Comment: that is the only way to access them other than reflection

Comment: ohk ,but then how they using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888191/how-do-i-build-the-android-sdk-with-hidden-and-internal-apis-available/13401572#comment112063930_13401572