# How to use IActivityWatcher

Tags: android

Hi Can anyone tell me how IActivityWatcher interface is used??

I'm trying to develop an application that records the amount of time that all installed applications were run. It is similar to an application "AppUsage" on Google play. When i decompiled it and checked he is using IActivityWatcher interface in his app. I googled regarding the same but hardly finding very little info which is not enough to proceed. Please help.

Comment: I think someone uses it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549763/how-to-inform-an-activity-that-another-activity-was-just-started

Comment: Thank You. I already Tried this but didnt serve my purpose, If u have any idea how to implement the above problem then please post it.